# PHP 7 strict type object to string conversion

Tags: php

I have a function which expects a string as input parameter:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

function testXml(string $xml) {
    echo "this is a string: " .$xml;
}
```

Now when I feed this function an object, I expect a Type Error to be thrown.
But this is not the case, an object of type SimpleXmlElement is silently converted to a string:
https://3v4l.org/lQdaZ

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the documentation of the [magic function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) [`__toString()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) explains:

> The `__toString()` method allows a class to decide how it will react when it is treated like a string.

Because the class [`SimpleXmlElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) implements the [`__toString()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php) magic method, it (the method) is invoked every time a `SimpleXmlElement` is used where a string is expected. The value returned by `__toString()` is used instead of the object.

It is difficult to tell if this is a feature or a bug<sup>1</sup>. The function `testXml()` currently expects a string as argument and you are not pleased by the fact that it silently accepts a `SimpleXmlElement` instead.

If you remove the type of its argument, the call to `__toString()` does not happen any more and the value of the `$xml` argument inside the function is the `SimpleXmlElement` object. The call to `__toString()` happens in the `echo "this is a string: " .$xml;` line and it's very convenient that you can print the value of `$xml` even if it is not a string.

If you think it is a bug then [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) (which expects strings as arguments) should complain about the type of `$xml` and should not print it. Not that convenient, isn't it?

---

<sup>1</sup> It is not a bug, this is how the language evolved. `__toString()` was introduced before [type declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) for scalar types and, in order to not break the existing behaviour, it is invoked if it's possible instead of triggering an error about incorrect type of the argument.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, alas, I find it irritating.

Comment: What I find more disturbing is, that the Object is converted to an empty string in a phpunit unit test

Comment: Is it a real object or a mock?

Comment: It is a real object

Comment: This has nothing to do with `__toString()`. Even an object with a `__toString()` method cannot be passed where a string is expected.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are passing the string (`$simpleXml`) and not the SimpleXmlElement (`$xml`) to the function.

Comment: Though it should be added that the OP's code would work in the unexpected way when it's executed without `declare(strict_types = 1);`. See: https://3v4l.org/r7eL6

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature that php is calling--if defined--the `__toString`-magic method of an object:

This code requires php@7:

```
<?php
class ClassImplementingToString
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return "hello world";
    }
}

function foo(string $foo)
{
    echo $foo;
}

foo(new ClassImplementingToString());
```

will output: `hello world`

[Sandbox example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3e2038ceda8a2e8fe325786973c771017bf5f580)

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to foo() must be of the type string, object given`

Comment: This has nothing to do with `__toString()`. Even an object with a `__toString()` method cannot be passed where a string is expected.

Comment: @AndreKR Are you talking php@5? This answer uses php@7 http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3e2038ceda8a2e8fe325786973c771017bf5f580

Comment: You forgot the `declare(strict_types = 1);`.